# A button that (when pressed) creates an combobox in its place and moves itself down to the row below

Tags: javafx, combobox

Long story short: 
I have an assignment that is going to interact with older people (patients) for medical purposes.

I have designed everything in scenebuilder and I am stuck at the moment.

The patients are going to fyll in some medical data, some days is going to require more input than others. Input such as heart rate, blood sugar, how they slept that night and so on.

I'm going to need a system that is adaptable since each day can vary on how much they want to fyll in. (depending on them and/or their doctor)

This is how the program is right now:
[The first 2-3 rows in the gridpane is my focus right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOUFK.png)

what i want is that when i press the ADD button, it will create an combobox in its plane and movie itself down a row in the gridpane.

I dont actually know if it good to do this with a gridpane or if anyone has any other recomendations ( all appreciated).

you can see that in the rows 6-9 are hardcoded what input is what. Since these options may change with time i will need to make it adjustable. That is why my first combobox reads its different inputpotions from the database.

My attempt so far:

```
@FXML
GridPane gridPane;

@FXML
Button addButton;

@FXML
ComboBox<String> addedCombo;

@FXML
String amountCombo;

int count = 0;

@FXML
public void addComboBoxButton() {

    amountCombo = "addedCombo";

    addedCombo = new ComboBox();
    addedCombo.setName(amountCombo + count);
    count++;

}
```

Im trying to create a function that created an combobox evertyime the ADDbutton is pressed and then add count to it.

For example if you press it 3 times you should've created 3 comboboxes that are named:

addedCombo0, addedCombo1, addedCombo2

The error i get is shown on setName() and it says: 
The method setName(String) is undefined for the type ComboBox

[This is how it should look like after the ADDbutton is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RrgP.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would not create any `ComboBox` in `FXML`. I would create a `List` to hold each new `ComboBox`. I would set the new `ComboBox`'s `UserData` to the row number.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a separate GridPane(or VBox) for handling the ComboBoxes within the grid. This way everytime when you add a comboBox, you dont need to alter the row numbers of all the rows down the grid.

Something like..

```
<GridPane>
  <children>
     <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
       <!-- Keep adding your combo boxes here -->
     </VBox>
     <Button text="Add" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />

     <Label text="Heart Rate" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
     <TextField GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
     <!-- Followed by your other rows.....>
  </children>
</GridPane>
```